# `react-native log-android` does not show console.log() invocations

Tags: android, logging, react-native, adb, console.log

How can I view arbitrary javascript logs with the react-native toolchain? Facebook's documentation [states `react-native log-android` should show them](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-console-logs), but I am not seeing anything when I write a trivial log such as in `index.android.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// ...

console.log("foo") // first log after imports
```

Would this show up in the `adb logcat` logs? This is through an emulated device, and oddly enough I can witness other trivial changes (such as, manipulations in font size), so I know my build system "works", but I can't see the logs for some reason.

Also, note that this is using an Ubuntu GNU/Linux development system, not OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please run following command in terminal. (where your app directory located)

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```